# Setting bash flags in subshells - does it affect parent shell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, subshell

I have this in a bash script:

```
(
  set -o pipefail
  echo "foobar" | bash
  set +o pipefail
)
```

do I need to reset pipefail setting, or can I just omit that line? In other words, does the pipefail setting in the subshell affect the parent?

So that means I assume that this:

```
(
  set -o pipefail
  echo "foobar" | bash
)
```

is really no different than the above?

Comment: they probably aren't called bash flags / settings...if you can correct me on the terminology that would be good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html):

> Changes made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell's execution environment.

You can test your case easily:

```
$ set +o pipefail
$ (set -o pipefail)
$ shopt -o pipefail
pipefail        off
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I though, so no need to unset things at the end of the subshell I guess